# How to solve this issue "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders"

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, npm-install

[Failed to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biF0G.png)I am running NodeJS and I can't seem to compile my project as shown in the picture, what should I do to fix this.
When I run "npm install" all the packages are properly installed.

Comment: Add some images of the error and  can include the package.json here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.